# Twitter Bootstrap breaking contents of div with several elements inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap to develop a responsive site.

I have two containers that have content which I don't want to break onto new lines if the window is resized.

I currently have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/23j8F/1/) which demonstrates.

I thought using clearfix on the parent container for each news item would work. But the text is breaking from the image on resize.

You can see this in [this image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66584/bs-site.png)

Any clues?

This is the basic css (although it's all in the fiddle):

```
   /* News items */
.news-item {
    padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
}

 .news-item p {
padding:0;
margin:0;   
}

.news-item img,
.news-item-text {
float:left;
}

.news-item-text {
padding:0 0 0 5px;  
}

.news-heading {
font-size:18px;
 }

 .news-tags {
font-family:ffs-italic;
font-size:12px; 
 }
```

This is the top of the html:

```
  <div class="row"><!-- breaking and buzzing -->
            <div class="span4"><!-- breaking news -->
                <h2>Breaking</h2>
                <div id="breakingNews" class="rounded clearfix">
                    <div class="news-item clearfix">
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="img/news/sm/sq01.jpg" width="54" height="54" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="news-item-text">
                            <p class="news-heading"><a href="">Omni Scents to launch...</a></p>
                            <p class="news-subheading">At vero eos fragrance line inspired</p>
                            <p class="news-tags"><a href="" class="pink">BEAUTY</a>, <a href="" class="pink">PRODUCTS</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-item clearfix">
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="img/news/sm/sq02.jpg" width="54" height="54" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="news-item-text">
                            <p class="news-heading"><a href="">IFF finishes year strong...</a></p>
                            <p class="news-subheading">Lorem ipsum in dolor contratis</p>
                            <p class="news-tags"><a href="" class="orange">INDUSTRY</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you be bit more clear, what do you mean by breaking, Do you want `Buzzing` to come below `Breaking` & Breaking products appear one beside another.

Comment: No I mean the content inside each news-item. I always want it to be 100% width of the parent container. So the square image, and paragraph next to it should always be in a row block. Does that make sense. Have a look at the image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You in those cases you need to float your divs and also specify a width for the div, like this:

```
.news-item {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
```

Also you need to determine the width of each `<p>`inside the divs, like this:

```
.news-item-text {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  width: 160px;
}
```

For responsive layout, you need to use the tag `@media`to set each width again, like:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .news-item {
      padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
    }

  .news-item-text {
      padding: 0 0 0 5px;
      width: 100px;
    }
}
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Yeah that looks correct, I like your answer, only that I was hoping to solve it for all the different max/min widths without having to code each one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .news-item a
     {
      display: block;
      float: left
     }
 .news-item-text
    {
    float: right;
    width: 75%; /* adjust this to fit */
    }
```

Comment: @lharby does this work? This code goes inside the breakpoint where you are facing issue.